# Adaptive streaming library (shaka / dash.js) that doesn't clear buffered video on seek?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, mpeg-dash, shaka

It seems that most adaptive streaming players clear the entire buffer whenever you seek (to a time that's not buffered). Even youtube - for example play a youtube video, seek a few minutes ahead, then back to the original location. There's a slight delay as the video has to reload

dash.js & shaka behave the same way and there's no easy way to change them

I was kinda able to patch DASH.js by [nooping this function](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/blob/d89b1f2b07c45e63d8da24aeb0688640bdeceff5/src/streaming/controllers/BufferController.js#L666) and that works - but results in some undesired behavior like a low-bitrate segment getting buffered and never getting upgraded even with excess bandwidth

Chrome actually buffers multiple ranges by default if you're streaming a plain mp4, but that's not DASH / adaptive. Does anyone know of a DASH implementation that supports this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any, but I'll shed some light on why Shaka Player doesn't.

When you don't clear the buffer, the browser has multiple ranges of buffered content.  This is complicated to track which regions are buffered and which segments map to those regions.  It is much simpler to track the last segment we've appended and move forward from there.  If we are playing forward and hit a region that is already buffered, we would need to track which segments are associated with that buffered range so we can pick up where we left off.  This isn't impossible, but it is much simpler to just start over.

The browser puts limits on how much content we can buffer.  So we clear content that is too far behind the playhead.  This will erase parts of the already buffered regions.  So if there is a region from 30-50 that maps to segments 6-8 that we've already buffered; if we clear up some data and now have only 40-50 buffered, we don't know which segments are still buffered.  Note that we can't always look at the times from the manifest to determine what times map to which segments since it may be inaccurate.

We track how much we have buffered ahead of the playhead to avoid buffering too much ahead (again because of browser limits).  Having multiple buffered ranges complicates how we calculate this.  Especially since when we append segments sequentially, there may also be gaps.  So we can't just look at the end of the current range to determine how much we have buffered.  Plus, having a lot of HD buffered at the end of the video doesn't help when we're at the start, so we would need to clear that to make room.

You also mention that the low-quality segments never go away.  This would happen in Shaka Player too.  We don't ever replace segments that are already downloaded.  This is again for simplicity (and it would only reasonably happen when paused).  So when we hit an already buffered region, we would just skip over it, even if we could download HD.  It is hard enough trying to determine which stream to play sequentially to keep playing in real time; adding to that having to determine if we have enough extra to replace already-buffered content would be too complex.